# Possible to use Telerik rad controls for WPF in an open source project?

Tags: wpf, open-source, telerik

I am working a project that is going to be made open source eventually. The performance of builtin WPF 4.0 datagrid is terrible. I am thinking of using Telerik controls to improve the performance of the application.

Is it possible to use telerik in an open-source project without providing the binaries such that only people who have telerik libs installed will be able to compile the project.

Questions:

Will telerik add something in the project file (or folder) that would allow people without a telerik license to use the their controls for free? (which I don't want)

I haven't bought telerik yet (so I do need to ask someone who has) but I remember for devexpress winforms, that they used to add a licx file (if memory serves me right) to the project that was unsafe to share due to license issues. Any similar files I need to be aware of for telerik?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to provide the redistributable binary, and let people get the buildable stuff from Telerik if they want it. You would have to provide a compatible license, so if you're one of those GPL folks, this approach is out. Your best bet might be to contact Telerik directly and get some advice from them.

Comment: I doubt it they are one of the worst abusers of open source and hey sell their products for thousands of dollars meaning they can afford to sue your butt off. Not worth the risk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyone who does not have a license to the Telerik grid would not be allowed or able to build your project. They would certainly be able to use it.

Assuming they were able to successfully build your project, there would generally be a runtime dialog that indicates the control is not licensed. I'm not sure if Telerik implements it this way though.

Generally, license information is embedded in the built assembly. This license information is generally stored on the developers machine and included by Visual Studio when building.

The license agreement can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/license-agreement/telerik-premium-collection.aspx). But if you purchase a license, you can distribute the assemblies as part of your application royalty-free.

> All product licenses are perpetual and
>   Royalty-free. You can ship the Telerik
>   products as part of solutions for
>   internal company use, hosted
>   applications, commercial solutions
>   deployed at end-users' sites or
>   shrink-wrapped software in which our
>   controls are integrated. For more
>   details, please review the EULA.

You can still open-source your project, but in order for others to build it they'd have to buy a license as well.

Comment: Be careful. The company mentioned closes the source as soon as the product becomes mature then you're screwed and their prices are not in the developer price range.